# How to implement y-axis ticks to range from 0 to 1000 with intervals of 250

Tags: chart.js

How to implement y-axis ticks to range from 0 to 1000 with intervals of 250?

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Chart.js Lines</title>

  <style type="text/css">
 .container {
    width: 80%;
  min-width:1000px;
    margin: 15px auto;
}
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<main class="container">
<div class="distribution_bar">
<canvas id="avrg_perform_lineChart" height="65"></canvas>
</div>
</main>

 <!-- Average performance line chart starts -->
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-/JqT3SQfawRcv/BIHPThkBvs0OEvtFFmqPF/lYI/Cxo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/4.4.0/chart.umd.js"
        integrity="sha512-6HrPqAvK+lZElIZ4mZ64fyxIBTsaX5zAFZg2V/2WT+iKPrFzTzvx6QAsLW2OaLwobhMYBog/+bvmIEEGXi0p1w=="
        crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
  <script>
if ($('#avrg_perform_lineChart').length) {
var lineChartCanvas = $("#avrg_perform_lineChart").get(0).getContext("2d");
var data = {
  labels: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar"],
  datasets: [
    {
      label: 'Clicks',
      data: [550,380, 340],
      borderColor: [
        'rgba(244,162,97)'
      ],
      borderWidth: 1,
      fill: false,
      pointBackgroundColor: "#ffffff",
      pointBorderColor: "rgba(244,162,97)"
    },
    {
      label: 'Earning',
      data: [99, 250, 750],
      borderColor: [
        'rgba(141, 137, 202)'
      ],
      borderWidth: 1,
      fill: false,
      pointBackgroundColor: "#ffffff",
      pointBorderColor: "rgba(141, 137, 202)"
    }
  ]
};
var options = {
  scales: {
    y: {
      beginAtZero: true,
      max: 1000,
      min: 0,
      stepSize: 250,
      ticks: {
        callback: function (value) {
          return value;
        },
      },
    },
    x: {
      grid: {
        display: false,
        drawBorder: false,
        color: "#ffffff",
      },
    },
  },
  elements: {
    line: {
      tension: 0.2,
    },
    point: {
      radius: 4,
    },
  },
};
var lineChart = new Chart(lineChartCanvas, {
  type: 'line',
  data: data,
  options: options
});
}
  </script>
  <!-- Average performance line chart ends -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: 1) move the `stepSize` property under `grid` (see [the docs](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/linear.html#tick-configuration)) 2) remove the `height="65"` attribute of the canvas (making an extremely small chart, if that is your intention, is a separate issue that you may work at that later - you need to alter the default fonts and change other options and it will probably still not look great at a height of 65px) See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f7bsw5yv/).